# PHP Global Timestamp for Caching of Permissions

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a web application inventory system which involves different levels of user permissions and micromanagement of individual permissions within these levels. So most admins have all permissions, but you could create an admin and strip them of a certain permission. Ultimately, these permissions are stored as a bitstring within a MySQL database, where a 1 means they have a permission and a 0 means that they do not. I am working on making the system more efficient without sacrificing security. Rather than run a database search and check permissions every single time a user wants to complete an action, I would like to cache permissions within the PHP Session variable along with a timestamp of when these permissions were pulled from the server.

```
$query_getUser = $this->User->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = ?");
$query_getUser->bindParam(1, $Email);
$query_getUser->execute();
$result = $query_getUser->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$date = new DateTime();

session_start();                        
$_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;                        
$_SESSION['Password'] = $Password;                      
$_SESSION['Timestamp']= $date->getTimestamp();      
$_SESSION['Permissions']= $result['Permissions'];
```

The major issue I have run into is where to store the global variable for this. What would be the most secure location? Essentially, I want to have the global current cache date stored somewhere where I can access it for a comparison in O(1) time.

Also, are there any major concerns with implementing permissions in this way? If user permissions are modified infrequently, and a new user not yet having permissions to pull until they are added to the system (so create_user does not cause a cache update, but modify_user does), is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: +1 for structured question and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

For complex applications having a normal global variable gets pretty messy. What I like to do is wrap the retrieval/storage mechanism in a class and let the class do all the work.

Something like this:

```
class Auth {
    public static function has_privilege($privilege) {
        $privileges = static::_get_privileges();
        if(in_array($privilege, $privileges)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected static function _get_privileges() {
        $from_session = $_SESSION['Privileges'];
        $last_update = $_SESSION['Timestamp'];
        if(time() - $last_update > 60*60*24) { // One day
            // Fetch them from the DB
        }
        else {
            return $from_session;
        }
    }
}
```

And then check a privilege like this:

```
if(\Auth::has_privilege('do_something')) {
     echo 'You can do something.';
} else {
     echo 'You cannot do something.';
}
```

It would be better to have all this as part of a `User` class, but this should give you an idea.

Now, in terms of security, that depends on your system. Default PHP session functionality stores session info in files in the `/tmp` directory, so as long as that directory is secure then your session will be secure. The thing you should be worried about most is session hijacking, but that is independent of your privilege storage issue.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this will basically set a time-out on the user's permissions. What I am trying to do is automatically time-out a user's permissions when there is a permissions change. So if, for example, a user is stripped of their permissions by an admin and they just logged in before that, that change will become effective the very next time they attempt an action which requires permission.

Comment: Then there's no way to store those in a session without having to query the DB every time, unless you want some other storage mechanism. What's wrong with querying the database every time for privileges?

Comment: Every query would require a search of the database for that user's permissions to see if they were allowed to do that action. Though a search does not take all that long, but it still does take time, especially when there could be thousands of users in the database, and potentially hundreds accessing the system at any one time. The end goal is an efficient, reasonably secure system (there's not much that will be done if someone logs in and walks away from their computer, other than a 15-30 minute inactivity time-out).

Comment: Well, if you're so worried about someone having "expired" privileges in their session, then you should really have one "master" location to store all privileges. You'll need to retrieve them from that location on each page load anyway, so why not a database? You can use a redis store instead of SQL database if you're worried about speed, but storing them in the session and then somehow expiring them when somebody else changes them is counter productive.